# Not able to cover the IsConverted Logic from test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

Class:

```
public class classname {
    public static void MethodName(List<Lead> listNew){

        Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();    
        for(Lead lead : listNew) {
            if (lead.IsConverted) {
                OppIds.add(lead.convertedOpportunityId);///Not able to cover this line from test class
            }
        }

        //Some logic is there
    }
}
```

Test Class:

```
static testmethod void testconvertlead(){
    Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
    lc.setLeadId(leadRecord.Id);

    LeadStatus convertStatus = [Select Id, MasterLabel from LeadStatus where IsConverted=true limit 1];
    lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);

    Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc)
}
```

Comment: Are u getting any error?

Comment: No error , Eventhough i am converting a lead from test class the below converted if condition is not covering                                                                                           
  if (lead.IsConverted) {
                OppIds.add(lead.convertedOpportunityId);///Not able to cover this line from test class
            }

Comment: Are you really sure the function is being called when the lead is converted?

Comment: yes it is calling

Comment: can you try adding IsConverted into SOQL of Test class? You are not retrieving that field.

Comment: We need more context to be able to answer this question. Please show how the method being tested is actually called and from what trigger context.

Answer (score 2):

You need to query the fileds and pass it to method and `lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);` is to be set.

```
@isTest
static void convertTest(){
  Lead lead=[select id from lead limit 1];
  Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert(); 
  lc.setLeadId(lead.id); 
  lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false); 
  lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted'); 
  Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc); 
  Lead[] passingLeads=[SELECT IsConverted,convertedOpportunityId,Id FROM Lead];
  classname.MethodName(passingLeads);
}
```

[Ref](https://github.com/sonicfurqan/Salesforce-Fundamentals/blob/master/Apex/Test%20Class/testForLeadConvert.cls)